# Sending commands to mininet hosts on a no-GUI server

Tags: shell, networking, network-programming, host, mininet

I have mininet installed on a server **without GUI** and I would like to send commands to my mininet hosts but I'm obviously not able to use "xterm h1" cause it cannot connect to display (there's no display, I'm on SSH).

Is there another way to send commands to hosts, one they are running, without using xterm? It would be super to control hosts, otherwise I can think of something like named pipes to talk directly to processes, but it would be a little too fine grained then what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
h1.sendCmd(some_command)
h2.cmd(some_command)
```

where h1, h2 are host nodes. Commands may be sent using Cmd (which waits for output) or using sendCmd(), which returns immediately, allowing subsequent monitoring using monitor().